# ImagickでOrientationを削除する方法

Tags: php, imagemagick, exif

お世話になります。
PHPの質問なのですが、Imagickで、
Orientationを削除する方法をどなたか教えて頂けませんでしょうか

お願いします！！

以下の方法で試しても、プロパティが削除されませんでした

```
$hogeImage = new Imagick('hogehoge.jpg');
$hogeImage->deleteImageProperty('Exif:Orientation');
$hogeImage->writeImage('converted_hogehoge.jpg');
var_dump(exif_read_data('converted_hogehoge.jpg'));//確認用
```

Comment: `deleteImageProperty`メソッド常に false 返しますね… なんじゃこりゃ…

Answer (score 1):

[[BUG] Imagick::deleteImageProperty() completely does not work · Issue #249 · mkoppanen/imagick](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/249)

「JPEGでは動かない」が正解でした。

[pel/pel: PHP Exif Library - library for reading and writing Exif headers in JPEG and TIFF files using PHP.](https://github.com/pel/pel)

代替案としてこれを使えば可能なようです。